# How Can I Connect Elephant IO to Socket IO Between PHP as Backend and React as FrontEnd

Tags: php, reactjs, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I am Trying to create a chat app using PHP as backend and React as frontend. I want the messages to be updated every time a change happens in the database (new message sent). As I searched the most common answer was sockets. But every tutorial covers how to connect between express and nodejs as backend and react as frontend, but my backend is PHP.

My PHP Code:

```
// $chats is the data pulled from the database 
$version = new Version1X("/");
$client = new Client($version);
$client->initialize();
$client->emit("chats", $chats);
$client->close();
```

My React Code:

```
import io from 'socket.io-client'
const socket = io("/").connect()
....


function App()
{
  socket.on('connection', function(socket)
    {
        console.log("test")
        socket.emit('chats', function(data)
        {
            console.log(data)
        })
    })

 ....rest of code
}
```